# Simple e-commerce setup

Tags: ecommerce

I am looking for the most simple e-commerce solution. I want to sell single files such as eBooks etc. It is just fine to use PayPal as the payment gateway.

My question is: do you know a simple platform that enables selling a low amount of single items. I have no prior experience with any e-commerce platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using something like Paypal's own shopping cart or Paypal buttons. You can create your site without worrying about the ecommerce aspects then copy/paste the "buy now" code from Paypal (you can generate the buttons on their site).

All order administration and management is then done via Paypal.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but it might help others stumbling across this question.

Try [binpress](http://www.binpress.com/) . You can design your store front for single or multiple products. Last time i tested it you could do that visually, there was no not to code anything.